# C# (UNITY) The best overloaded method match for X has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I'm a complete C# Newb. I've watched about 10 tutorials and mostly have had success, and every error I've encountered I've been able to find a solution save this one which has stumped me for 3 hours now. I'm trying, in one class, to assign the values for the variables in one object to another, which both reside in another class. This is in UNITY if it helps:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class selectPart : MonoBehaviour {

    public PartDirectory scriptAccess;
    //public PartDirectory.HumunculusPart partAccess;

    void SetCurrentHead ()
    {

        //currentHead.text = headChoices [0];
        //GameObject.Find ("Examiner").GetComponent<PartDirectory> ().selectedHead.partSpecies = GameObject.Find ("Examiner").GetComponent<PartDirectory> ().turtleHead.partSpecies;
        scriptAccess.selectedHead = scriptAccess.turtleHead;
    }
}
```

And both objects were defined in the following class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PartDirectory : MonoBehaviour {

    public class HumunculusPart
    {
        public string partType;
        public string partGenus;
        public string partSpecies;
        public int health;
        public int armor;
        public int strength;

    public HumunculusPart(string pType, string gType, string pSpecies, int hlth, int armr, int str)
    {
        partType = pType;
        partGenus = gType;
        partSpecies = pSpecies;
        strength = str;
        armor = armr;
        health = hlth;

    }
    }
    public HumunculusPart selectedHead = new HumunculusPart("Head","blank","blank","0","0","0");
    public HumunculusPart turtleHead = new HumunculusPart ("Head", "Animal", "Turtle", 9, 10, 2);
}
```

I've removed all irrelevant code, and if I'm missing something obvious I could've found in a guide, well then go ahead and savage me because this is killing me. I left some commented out failcode in case it helps. In general I am having a very tough time accessing objects from other classes, both the entire object and their individual variables.

Comment: You have not declared the class, try `scriptAccess = new PartDirectory();` before `scriptAccess.selectedHead = scriptAccess.turtleHead;`. PS: Actually your problem might be on this line `public HumunculusPart selectedHead = new HumunculusPart("Head","blank","blank","0","0","0");` change it to `public HumunculusPart selectedHead = new HumunculusPart("Head","blank","blank",0,0,0);` since the last 3 parameters need to be integers not strings.

Comment: I have a million questions but you completely got it. I was so concerned with others peoples similar issues I never even noticed I put int variables IN QUOTES. I'm so sorry, you're a life saver. Thank you!